# Why does my Applescript loop fail almost all the time? Oddly, it works sometimes

Tags: loops, applescript, reminders

The code below is used to run a sample text in TextEdit. There about 14 iterations and the loop can fail in any one of them. Below is an updated simplified version of the script. Its still giving me the same problem

[Compare the code in the new image with the dialog result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txNeM.png)

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"

    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        tell the front document
            set nameList to the first paragraph
            set remindersList to {}
            set lineCount to count the paragraphs
            repeat with i from 2 to lineCount
                set reminderName to paragraph i
                set end of remindersList to reminderName
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell

    tell application "Reminders"
        set newList to make new list
        set name of newList to nameList
        set reminderDate to date
        set listAccount to account
        lineCount = lineCount - 2
        repeat with i from 1 to lineCount
            tell list nameList                  
                set newremin to make new reminder
                set reminderName to item i of remindersList
                set {remName, remBody1, remBody2} to {text item 1, text item 2, text item 3} of reminderName
                set name of newremin to remName
                set body of newremin to remBody1 & return & remBody2
                set due date of newremin to (current date) + (1 * days)
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: You might want to post a few of your error messages and the failing line number (if you have that info) as well to give others more insight into what you are seeing,

Comment: I'll have to find a way to upload the file which the script is reading. The script, as I have modified it above, is in its complete form

Comment: @adrienalain Please state exactly what error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Actually, I can see you've enclosed the main bit of your script in a `try` block, then instructed that block to return the most incredibly unhelpful piece of information, namely how far through the looping process you got.  Why?  Try just getting rid of the `try` block altogether and reading the error message (and telling us what it is).  I don't see why you should need a `try` block anyway.  Get rid of it permanently.  Also, run the script inside _Script Editor_ during debugging phase (you'll have to get rid of the `on run {input, parameters}` line to do so).

Comment: Thanks for responding!! I did what you said. In Script Editor, the script completes the third loop and gives me... error "Reminders got an error: Can’t get list \"Exhibicion
\"." number -1728 from list "Exhibicion
"

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner - I wasn't aware you had replied. The second script is soooooo much better than the first, so well done. The fact that it happens with some lists and not others implies there's something specific to the way those lists are being handled. Obviously, I don't have all the information, so, for example, I can't see what the contents of your _TextEdit_ document is, which plays a big part in the script's functionality, depending what data it's feeding to it. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ What I notice, however, is that the error you provided has cited the name of the list as `"Exhibicion "`, not `"Exhibicion"`, i.e. there's a trailing space in its name at the end.  My guess is that's not supposed to be there, and that you don't have a list that has a name with a space at the end.  Hence, _Reminders_ cannot find that list.  Therefore, I suggest you double-check your text file and resolve any formatting issues to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: hmmm, there is no list called "Exhibicion "! It seems that Applescript put the space at the end because I didn't. Is that at all possible? If so, it could be the cause of the random failure. I'll check that out later today. "Exhibicion" is the only test file I'm using.

Comment: AppleScript won't insert a space like that of its own accord, and that space is in a very specific position.  I guarantee you that the problem is there.  It's looking for a list called "Exhibicion ", but it cannot find it.  So your variable that contains the names of your lists has a value in it of "Exhibicion ", and it's retrieved this value from...?  Your text input ?  Text file ?  Is the word "Exhibicion" on a line of its own in a text file, that ends with a space you can't see ?

Comment: Veeeery interesting! That space is not on the TextEdit document. To try to figure this out, I put a "-" before "EXHIBICION" and another after at the first chance after the creation of the variable. See the result in the new image I just mounted. Is a carriage return causing the second "-" to be on the second line? And is that being interpreted as a space by Applescript?

Comment: Figured it out! The TextEdit document was delimited to create 3 columns for Reminders, one for the name and 2 for the body, but the first paragraph, "EXHIBICION", had no delimiters. So it calculated 2 spaces. This is my guess, anyway. My temporary fix is to remove the last 2 characters. Works perfectly. Long term fix is to adjust the Vectorworks script, which produced the list, to put in those delimiters in the first line. Thanks for walking me through this, Christofer! Your help is greatly appreciated!